# How to create buy order using Binance API on python using all my selected coin instead of setting the quantity of what coin I want to buy?

Tags: python, binance

Say I have $200 USDT, I want to place an order to buy ETHUSDT using 100% of my $200 USDT. Is there a way I can place an order using 100% of my USDT and not how many ETH I want to buy?

This is the code that I am using.

```
buy_order = client.create_test_order(symbol="ETHUSDT, side='BUY', type='MARKET', quantity=10)
```

This buys 10 ETH right? But I wanted to buy $200 worth of ETH. How can I do this?

Answer (score 8):

First you have to calculate how much ETH $200 can get you.

```
#First get ETH price
eth_price = client.get_symbol_ticker(symbol="ETHUSDT")

# Calculate how much ETH $200 can buy
buy_quantity = round(200 / float(eth_price['price']))

# Create test order
order = client.create_test_order(
        symbol='ETHUSDT',
        side=Client.SIDE_BUY,
        type=Client.ORDER_TYPE_MARKET,
        quantity=buy_quantity
    )

 # The 200 in buy_quantity is the amount of money you want to spend on ETH.
```

Comment: The issue with this is that market price fluctuates. So if there is slippage, your order will fail. You can use quoteOrderQty instead for market orders, but for futures this is not implementing. Trying to find a solution myself.

Answer (score 3):

parameter `quoteOrderQty` allows to specify the total quoteOrderQty spent or received in the MARKET order. It refers to "quote asset", e.g. for ETHUSDT pair USDT is a "quote asset". Therefore if you want to spend 200 USDT then use

```
buy_order = client.create_test_order(symbol='ETHUSDT', side='BUY', type='MARKET', quoteOrderQty=200)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `quoteOrderQty=` instead of `quantity=` . amount the user wants to spend (when buying) or receive (when selling) of the quote asset, applicable to MARKET orders .

```
buy_order = client.create_test_order(symbol="ETHUSDT, side='BUY', type='MARKET', quoteOrderQty=10)
```